# TomEE 4 JPA issue

Tags: jpa, cdi, apache-tomee

I am trying out simple JPA example on TomEE 4.0.0 and I am not able to get PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED working

If I make my session bean Stateless and leave PersistenceContextType then it works fine

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "xxx" )
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

If I keep my session bean as Stateless and then try to use this

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "xxx", type = PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED))
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

it gives me an error while deploying, which is perfectly fine and in line with expectation.

However now when I make my bean as @Stateful, then also it gives me an error

```
Managed ejbs are not capable of using EntityManagers with EXTENTED persistence.  Convert your bean to a Stateful ejb or update the "java:comp/env/com.testwebservice.TestJPAService/entityManager" PersistenceContext reference to PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION.
```

Can some one please help, I am really confused for this

Comment: Are you sure, your change was recognized ? A clean build might help to make sure the changes are picked up. If you still face it, can you add the whole stacktrace ?

Comment: On a sidenote, TomEE is not at version 4.0. It is with 1.0-beta1 released and it uses OpenEJB 4.0-beta1 release

Answer (score 0):

`@Stateful` EXTENDED persistence contexts are tested in numerous ways in the TomEE build and also in the Java EE TCK.

Likely this is something else completely.  We do our best to warn you when you make obvious mistakes as you note with the incorrect combination of `@Stateless` with `PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED`

Looking at the JNDI name which contains `com.testwebservice.TestJPAService` and given the fact it was `@Stateless` before it was changed to `@Stateful`, my guess is that this bean is also an `@WebService` which is illegal.  `@Stateful` beans cannot be `@WebService` beans.  Without a proper check to prevent this mistake, my guess is that the bean is actually being deployed twice; once as a `@Stateful` bean and once as an pojo `@WebService`.  The pojo web service is the one causing the error.

In case that is the error, I've filed a JIRA for us to explicitly [check that condition](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENEJB-1768).